# Protected box overlaps with "Not the question you're looking for"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: Overlapping design elements]

If you zoom in you can see that the top of the `?` and other tall characters overlap into the protection notice box.

Example [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me).

Fairly sure this is gaming specific as haven't noticed it on other sites.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This was addressed during one of the various site design overhauls in the past. This is what you now see:

[image: Highly Active Question box not overlapping text]